# I can't change width of <a> without making it float or block

Tags: css, width

Why is it like this?

What's the reason inside it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you float it, you implicitly make it a block element.  And unlike inline elements (**a** included among these), block elements can be assigned a width and height.  Here's a [good explanation of block vs. inline differences](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline.php).

**Edit:** removed "have layout" as part of description of block elements, this [isn't quite true](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)...

Comment: Why you say "you implicitly make it a block element."?What's your evidence?

Comment: It's in the official CSS spec at w3.org.

Comment: The W3's wording on it is admittedly a little vague, but, describing the possible float properties, the spec says: "The element generates a block box that is floated to the left." Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position .  In other words, inline element or no, it's going to be a block element once the float is applied.

Answer (score 3):

`<a>` is an inline element and flows amongst regular text. As Ben says, floating elements implicitly converts them to "block" elements.

One solution is to use the CSS style `display: inline-block` - the link will then work much like an image - flow inline with text, but also allow you to set a width/height.

Answer (score 1):

The premise is incorrect.

use an inline-block

```
<a href="" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;  background-color:Red;">abc</a>
```